# trying to use Python to tell numbers apart

Tags: python, regex

I'm pretty sure the answer to this lies in regular expressions but I'm not getting it right.

I have a list of text. Within that text I'm parsing out a bunch of different things but I'm scratching my head in particular at telling certain numbers from one another. I have client numbers that are sequential but have gaps (1, 2, 4, 5.. 1900, 1901, 1905), I have year numbers (2001, 2015, 2016), and finally I have billed amounts (0.00, 43.24, 1,925.00, 10,324.95).

I need to be able to tell the billed amounts, which include commas when the amount is $1,000 or more and always include two numbers to the right of the decimal, from year numbers, which don't use any commas and don't have a decimal point. The client numbers I can detect just by where they are located.

I've been trying to do it by testing for a regular expression of:

```
currency_matcher = re.compile('\d*[,]*\d*\d[.]\d*')
if currency_matcher.search(line) != None:
    #assume currency
```

I haven't specifically tried looking for the years yet but assumed I'd do a similar thing like:

```
year_matcher = re.compile('\d\d\d\d')
```

I've also considered using try and except but am just beginning that experimentation as I type this.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

EDIT: trying to add some clarity
I have a text document that is broken into a python list like this:

```
[
  "1", "Alice Alwen", "12345 Oak Street", "Anytown, US 12345", "0.00", "123.45", "2007", "Pontiac", 
  "2", "Bob Bobberson", "1919 Elm Road", "Metropolis, US 11111", "123.45", "0.00", "2016", "Sherman Tank", "2105", "Bradley Fighting Vehicle", "5", 
  "Carl Carlson", "9854 Willow Way #1", "Gotham City, GA 34567", "1,001.00", "2,300.00", "2015", "Batmobile - used"
]
```

I can always tell when the client ID is because it's the first thing. After the personal info there are two "currencies" in my example (there are four in my dataset but same idea). I'd like to be able to ID these and extract them. Towards the end of the row you will also see a year number associated with a vehicle. I don't need these but I need to make sure I don't accidentally grab them when I grab the currency.

I have already made a note (via code) of where each customer is in my dataset so I can do something like:

```
for cust in customers:
    currency_list = []
    for line in lines[begin_line : end_line]:
        if {magical regex here}:
            currency_list.append(line)
    {pseudo code to extract currency into my DataFrame}
```

hopefully that's more helpful, if not, I'm happy to add more.

Edit 2: actual code
I guess, while I'm at it, here is what I have written, it's erroring out but it also may be logically inaccurate:

```
life_total_dict = {}
currency_matcher = re.compile('\d*[,]*\d*\d[.]\d*')
for index, row in customers.itterrows():
    start_row = row["Line Number"]
    end_row = row["End Line Number"]

    currency_counter = 0
    for line in workable_lines[range(start_row, end_row)]:
        #if re.search(currency_matcher,line) != None:
        if currency_matcher.search(line) != None:
            if currency_counter == 1:
                life_total_dict[index] = line.strip()
                currency_counter += 1
            else:
                currency_counter += 1
print(life_total_dict)
customer = customer.append(life_total_dict, ignore_index=True)
```

If you're wondering about that weird counter, I actually only need the second currency amount. The first, third and fourth are just noise to me.

Comment: Hi Michael. I can see that you put some effort into your question. I have trouble understanding what exactly you need. Could you please provide us a demo file (just include the content in the question) and the desired output for that file?

Comment: will do. Sorry for the lack up clarity. Updating, give me a few minutes.

Comment: So you need a function that can tell whether a string is a billed amount, right?

Comment: @Tai That's is correct. I need to be able to tell the "1,111.11" and "11.11" from the "1111".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Brief

Assuming you're just asking for the regex (looks like the rest of your code is good), you can see both regular expressions below in use against your sample data set.

**Note**: The result of `Year` also includes the result of `id`. **The OP specified they have logic to differentiate between the two**, thus, I don't feel it's necessary to add the logic to my answer.

---

### Code

```
\d+(,\d+)*\.\d+$       # Currency
\d{4}$                 # Year
```

#### Usage

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/EVXCNq)

```
import re

array = ["1", "Alice Alwen", "12345 Oak Street", "Anytown, US 12345", "0.00", "123.45", "2007", "Pontiac", "2", "Bob Bobberson", "1919 Elm Road", "Metropolis, US 11111", "123.45", "0.00", "2016", "Sherman Tank", "2105", "Bradley Fighting Vehicle", "5", "Carl Carlson", "9854 Willow Way #1", "Gotham City, GA 34567", "1,001.00", "2,300.00", "2015", "Batmobile - used"]
r1 = r"\d+(,\d+)*\.\d+$"
r2 = r"\d{4}$"

for s in array:
    if re.match(r1, s):
        print "Currency: " + s
    if re.match(r2, s):
        print "Year: " + s
```

---

### Explanation

#### Currency

- [`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match): Asserts position at the start of the string (`^`) when matching.
- `\d+` Match one or more digits
- `(,\d+)*` Match the following any number of times

  - `,` Match the comma character `,` literally
  - `\d+` Match one or more digits
- `\.` Match the dot character `.` literally
- `\d+` MAtch one or more digits
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

#### Year

- [`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match): Asserts position at the start of the string (`^`) when matching.
- `\d{4}` Match any digit exactly 4 times
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Comment: Wow. this is an amazingly well constructed reply. Thanks. I popped it into jupyter, whole cloth, and it worked. integrating it back to my code add further learning from it should be straight forward.

Comment: @MichaelAmos I'm glad I could help! Let me know if you need any further clarification on anything

Answer (score 2):

Using `regex` you can accomplish this

```
currency_matcher = re.compile("^(\d+,)*\d+\.(\d{2})$")
...
if currency_matcher.search(line.strip()) != None:
    pass
```

Comment: awesome. thanks. Once I implement this I will mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that avoids regex is to use type conversions.  It assumes `ID` and `year` values don't overlap.

```
minyear = 2000
new_data = []

for x in data:
    try:
        float_val = float(x)
        int_val = int(float_val)
        if float_val == int_val:
            if int_val >= minyear:
                new_data.append((int_val, "year"))
            else:
                new_data.append((int_val, "id"))
        else:  
            new_data.append((float_val, "amount"))
    except ValueError:
        new_data.append((x, "string"))
```

Output of `new_data`:

```
[(1, 'id'),
 ('Alice Alwen', 'string'),
 ('12345 Oak Street', 'string'),
 ('Anytown, US 12345', 'string'),
 (0, 'id'),
 (123.45, 'amount'),
 (2007, 'year'),
 ('Pontiac', 'string'),
 (2, 'id'),
 ('Bob Bobberson', 'string'),
 ('1919 Elm Road', 'string'),
 ('Metropolis, US 11111', 'string'),
 (123.45, 'amount'),
 (0, 'id'),
 (2016, 'year'),
 ('Sherman Tank', 'string'),
 (2105, 'year'),
 ('Bradley Fighting Vehicle', 'string'),
 (5, 'id'),
 ('Carl Carlson', 'string'),
 ('9854 Willow Way #1', 'string'),
 ('Gotham City, GA 34567', 'string'),
 ('1,001.00', 'string'),
 ('2,300.00', 'string'),
 (2015, 'year'),
 ('Batmobile - used', 'string')]
```